# Creating random file in just one line but with specific length

Tags: files, random, head

I want to make a file (random content) but with just one 1 MB large line inside it

I have tried using this command but it didn't work :

```
head -n 1 -c 1m /dev/urandom > /sdcard/file.txt
```

How to do it properly?
I just want a file that contain random 1 MB data but only in a single line.

Comment: What set of characters are allowed on that line? For example, does it need to be valid UTF-8? Are control characters ok? How long should the line be?

Comment: @Kusalananda the above command doesn't work, it make a file, but it has many line inside, is there a way to make it to be just one line?

Comment: @IISomeOneII Yeah, you are overriding the `-n` option with `-c`. Use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
{ tr -d '\n' </dev/urandom | head -c 1m; printf '\n'; } >/sdcard/file.txt
```

Assuming GNU `head`, this would get one megabytes of (quite possibly binary, unprintable) data from `/dev/urandom` without any newlines in it, and then add a newline at the end.  The output would be saved to `/sdcard/file.txt`.  This single "line" would not be a proper line of text as it may well include nul bytes.

If you just want alphanumeric data,

```sh
{ tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 1m; printf '\n'; } >/sdcard/file.txt
```

This would remove all non-alphanumeric characters from the random stream from `/dev/urandom`, chop it off at 1 MB, and then add a newline character as before.

Answer (score 1):

- Read from `/dev/urandom`.
- Filter out the characters that you don't want to have on the line, such as newlines, null bytes, any other control character, etc.
- Stop at the desired number of bytes or characters.
- Add a newline character.

For example, to have 1,000,000 ASCII printable characters:

```
{ </dev/urandom \
  LC_ALL=C tr -dc ' -~' |
  head -c 1000000 &&
  echo
} >/sdcard/file.txt
```